# File size change when using TCP

Tags: c#, file, tcp, transfer

I send a 4 MB file by tcp to the local server. But the file is stored at 36 MB on the local server.

What is the problem with?

I convert file to string (base64) and add to my json. then Convert json to byte[] and send it.

Client send byte to server:

```
await nwStream.WriteAsync(json, 0, json.Length);

NetworkStream streams = client.GetStream();
int Q = 0;
int M = json.Length;
int ss = 150001;

bool go = true;
while (go)
{
    if(M< ss)
    {
        go = false;
        ss = M;
    }
    if (M < 0)
    {
        go = false;
        ss = M + ss;
    }
    await streams.WriteAsync(json, Q,ss);
    Q += ss;
    M -= ss;
}
```

and Server side get byte[]:

```
Byte[] bytes = new Byte[150001];
int i;
try
{
    // Loop to receive all the data sent by the client.
    while ((i = await stream.ReadAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0)
    {
        // bytes contains received data in byte[].
        // Translate data bytes to a UTF-8 string.
        byte[] receivedBuffer = new byte[i];
        Array.Copy(bytes, receivedBuffer, i);
        data += System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(receivedBuffer);
        if (data.IndexOf("}") > 0)
        {
            break;
        }
    }


}
catch (Exception ex)
{

}
```

**Edit:**

and Save File,  I Encoding 'data' to UTF8 string, then convert to DeserializeObject.

```
             var pi = Convert.FromBase64String(picbas64);
        var x = (Bitmap)((new ImageConverter()).ConvertFrom(pi));
        string path = @"pic\Operation\" + name + ".jpg";
        var ZZ = x;
        ZZ.Save(path);
        return path;
```

Comment: You did not mention yet that you extract the base64 string from JSON and convert it back to binary. You do so, or?

Comment: @KlausGütter yes, i Encoding 'data' to UTF8 string, then convert to DeserializeObject.

Comment: Why don't yout just write `pi` to the file?

Comment: @KlausGütter i fix it, But the size issue is still there.

Comment: When you convert from Base64, you receive a `byte[]`. That array contains the Image bytes. You need a MemoryStream (`MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream([Your Byte Array])`). Then, use `Image.FromStream(ms, true)` to get the Image object. Use `Image.Save()` to sve the Image to disc. Don't forget to specify the Image type, otherwise your Image will be saved in PNG format (no matter what the original format was).

Comment: @Jimi i find problem in Convert image to `byte[]`. `imageIn.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)` is true! and then return `ms.ToArray()`. it is work. if i chose png, file size be changed.

Comment: Yes, of course the Image size can be different. Those are two different formats that have two different compression algorithms. When you do: `imageIn.Save(ms, [format])`, if `[format]` (the `ImageFormat` you specify) is not the same as the `imageIn` format, the file size will be different, because the Image has been converted to a different format. If you want to preserve the `imageIn` format, you can write: `imageIn.Save(ms, imageIn.RawFormat)`. The `RawFormat` property indicates the original File format of the Image.

Comment: @Jimi Tnx Man for helping about `RawFormat`.